# How to read shapefile with DotSpatial while I don't have dbf,prj,shx

Tags: dotspatial

I'm writing application to read and display shapefile.
I'm using DotSpatial 2.0.1 ( because I have Visual Studio 2017 )

Now I have shapefile to read.

If I have all the package: shp,shx,dbf,prj I'm using

```
Shapefile.OpenFile(path)
```

to read all the data: Features, Attributes , it's OK

But now I have only `shp` and OpenFile throws

```
System.IO.FileNotFoundException: can't find file 'name.dbf'
```

So what is the correct way to read single `shp`?

Comment: You can't, without all the files you don't have a shapefile

Comment: I have other opinion. I tried to import this file into ZWCAD using Spatial Manager and 50 points is imported. Similar would be enough.

Comment: While it's theoretically possible, directly in C/C++/C# (or any other language) to do this, you can't use a library which correctly expects all the required files to be present. You would then need to implement your own reader (which I have done in C, Java, JavaScript, and Python) and somehow mate it to the display.

Comment: Ok, thanks for Your answer.